# I need some method to check if an IPv6 address is in a net range in python

Tags: python, ipv6

I need to do this as part of validation, I have a solution for IPv4.
But since IPv6 can have many formats, I am not able to find the exact solution.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 2):

There many way to solve you problem. You can start from the solution for similar task:

- [Checking for IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827961/checking-for-ip-addresses/11828000#11828000)

The idea is to use the `socket` module from Python:

```
socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, address)
```

Comment: So now with inet_pton i get the binary format of the IP address , But how can i check if that was in the network range.

Answer (score 2):

Since Python 3.3, you can use

```
import ipaddress
ipaddress.ip_address(ip) in ipaddress.IPv6Network(network)
```

For example,

```
import ipaddress
ip = "2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334"
network = "2001:db8:85a3::/64"
test = ipaddress.ip_address(ip) in ipaddress.IPv6Network(network)
print(test)   # True
```

There is also a [backport for Python 2.6+](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2-ipaddress).

**EDIT:**
You can use the following function as well which supports both IPv4 and IPv6

```
ipaddress.ip_network(addr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [IPy](https://github.com/haypo/python-ipy/). It is really useful when dealing with IP addresses and subnets in Python.